# share field template between node display and views

Tags: entities, theming

Is there an easy way to share the same field template for both node display and views output?

Perhaps this requires a template.php template_files candidate addition?

Answer (score 1):

Might have to do this: [CCK Formatters](https://www.drupal.org/project/cck_formatters), hoping there may be an easier way. Here is a quote about CCK Formatters (from the module's project page):

> This package is a collection of add-on formatters for various CCK fields. Each provided sub-module in this package should be a self-contained single formatter.
>
> CCK fields support an arbitrary number of "formatters", swappable code that renders a field. In Drupal 6 these are essentially theme functions, although in Drupal 5 they are not always. It is possible for any module to define new formatters for field types it doesn't define itself, which creates a very powerful way to extend and theme a field in any of the myriad ways that a field can appear.
>
> This module is an "incubator" for new field formatters. Because each formatter may have its own development cycle, there will probably not be stable releases of the entire suite. If a specific formatter gets particularly popular or requires a more full-featured release cycle, it should likely be spun off to its own project.